# Yii's CController::forward() can specify parameters to pass to the action?

Tags: model-view-controller, yii, controller

I want to use [CController::forward()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#forward-detail) instead of redirect or instantiating the controller and directly calling the action, because this way `Yii::app()->controller->action->id` correctly shows the action that ultimately ran.
Although I don't see in the documentation how to specify parameters to pass to the forwarded action, because the `$route` parameter is a string, not an array.

```
public function actionIndex() {
  $this->forward('/otherCtrl/view'); // how to pass a parameter here?
```

otherController.php:

```
public function actionView( $id ) {
  //get the id here
```

Comment: It's not possible with `forward()`, only `redirect()` supports passing of parameters. This makes sense since `forward()` does not change the user browser's URL.

Comment: You're right, but just calling `actionView()` directly doesn't change the URL either, and you _can_ pass it parameters.

Comment: The context of parameters in `forward()` and `redirect()` is GET parameters, in `actionView()` these are normal parameters for the view.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters injected into action method comes from `$_GET`. So if you need to pass `$id` into forwarded action, you need to set value in `$_GET` array:

```
$_GET['id'] = 'some id';
```

But using `forward()` is basically always a sign of bad design of application - I suggest to extract shared logic into separate method/component, and avoid using `forward()` or calling controller actions directly.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
$this->forward('/otherCtrl/view/id/'.$id);
```

Query string depends on your URL settings.